# Apps on desktop like on mobile

Tags: gnome

Is there a way to have your apps on the desktop and to be able to open them with a single click? (with no fancy highlightings when hovering or clicking)

And is there a way to have folders like on mobile, which have a preview, and don't open in a file manager?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?